# Change non zero values to 1 in Scala Spark DF

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark Dataframe

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|_c0|_c1|_c2|_c3|_c4|_c5|_c6|_c7|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  0|  0|0,3|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|  0|1,1|  0|  0|1,4|  0|  0|  0|
|  0|2,1|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|  0|  0|  0|3,3|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|  0|  0|  0|  0|4,4|  0|4,6|  0|
|  0|  0|5,2|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|6,0|  0|  0|  0|  0|6,5|6,6|  0|
|  0|  0|7,2|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

is it possible to change all the values with ',' to 1? like this in Spark Scala?

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|_c0|_c1|_c2|_c3|_c4|_c5|_c6|_c7|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  0|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|  0|  1|  0|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|
|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|  0|  0|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  0|  1|  0|
|  0|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|  1|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  1|  0|
|  0|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code.

**Expressions**

```
scala> val colExpr = df
.columns
.map(c => 
        when(trim(col(c)) =!= "0", lit(1))
        .otherwise(col(c))
        .as(c)
)
```

**Applying Expression**

```
scala> df.select(colExpr:_*).show(false)
```

**Final Ouput**

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|_c0|_c1|_c2|_c3|_c4|_c5|_c6|_c7|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|0  |0  |0  |1  |0  |0  |0  |0  |
|0  |1  |0  |0  |1  |0  |0  |0  |
|0  |1  |0  |0  |0  |0  |0  |0  |
|0  |0  |0  |1  |0  |0  |0  |0  |
|0  |0  |0  |0  |1  |0  |1  |0  |
|0  |0  |1  |0  |0  |0  |0  |0  |
|1  |0  |0  |0  |0  |1  |1  |0  |
|0  |0  |1  |0  |0  |0  |0  |0  |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```